# Add new column with literal value to a struct column in Dataframe in Spark Scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with the following schema:

```
root
 |-- docnumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
           |-- codevent: int (nullable = true)
```

I need to add a column inside `event.data` so that the schema would be like:

```
root
 |-- docnumber: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
           |-- codevent: int (nullable = true)
           |-- needtoaddit: int (nullable = true)
```

I tried

- ```scala
  dataframe.withColumn("event.data.needtoaddit", lit("added"))
  ```

  but it adds a column with name `event.data.needtoaddit`
- ```scala
  dataframe.withColumn(
    "event",
    struct(
      $"event.*",
      struct(
        lit("added")
          .as("needtoaddit")
      ).as("data")
    )
  )
  ```

  but it creates an ambiguous column named `event.data` and again I have a problem.

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

**Spark 3.1+**

To add fields inside struct columns, use [**`withField`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#withField(fieldName:String,col:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

```scala
col("event.data").withField("needtoaddit", lit("added"))
```

---

Input:

```scala
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("1", 2)))
    .select(
        col("_1").as("docnumber"),
        struct(struct(col("_2").as("codevent")).as("data")).as("event")
    )
df.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- docnumber: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- event: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- data: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |    |-- codevent: long (nullable = true)
```

Script:

```scala
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "event",
    col("event.data").withField("needtoaddit", lit("added"))
)

df2.printSchema()
// root
//  |-- docnumber: string (nullable = true)
//  |-- event: struct (nullable = false)
//  |    |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
//            |-- codevent: int (nullable = true)
//            |-- needtoaddit: int (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're kind of close. Try this code:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn(
    "event", 
    struct(
        struct(
            $"event.data.*", 
            lit("added").as("needtoaddit")
        ).as("data")
    )
)
```

Comment: after teste better it won't work, the event data was losted when i run this code

Comment: if i add "event", struct($"event.*", struct($"event.data.*",... it won't work only add one column to data

Comment: you should not add event. that will overwrite the new data column with the existing data column.